# Liferay spring integration

Tags: java, spring, liferay

I try to use Spring to develop liferay portlets (version 6.0.6), could i use models and services generated by ServiceBuilder as spring bean?
I tried to import generated spring context in my own, but i got many errors in tomcat log. Maybe the best way is creation of own layer model and services using hibernate for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you go ahead and create your own service and persistence classes.  Those have nothing to do with UI, so you can use them whether you plunge ahead with portal or not.

If you're using Spring already, and you're planning to move on to portal, you should be thinking about [Spring portal](http://books.dzone.com/articles/hello-world-portlet-using-Spring-3-portlet-MVC).  Now it's just the same as Spring web MVC, just with different controllers.